# Photoshop script to fit artboard on screen

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, artboard, zoom

I am here because I did not find solution.

**Problem:**

- I have 4 artboards.
- I need a script (or action) to "fit artboard on screen" or zoom in specific artboard. (NOT fit layer on screen)
- There is a option in top menu panel/View/Fit artboard on screen. It works well when I use it with mouse click.

**But:**

1. When I try to record the `Action`:

   - Click on use `Insert Menu Item`: `Fit artboard on screen`, press OK
   - Nothing is recorded in the action
2. I also tried to click the menu item at `View > Fit artboard on screen`, but there is still nothing added to action panel during recording.
3. The last thing I tried was to use the Scripting listener plugin but it didn't output working code for this action.
4. I can record `View > Fit on screen` as an Action, which fits all 4 artboards on screen and I need to focus/zoom in/fit on screen just one artboard.

What do i mean is on images:
[image: fit artboard on screen]
...
[image: my goal]

---

This is code for action "Fit on screen". How could it be edited for "Fit artboard on screen"? Or is there another way to get my problem solved? Thank you all!

```
    var desc12 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref3 = new ActionReference();
        var idMn = charIDToTypeID( "Mn  " );
        var idMnIt = charIDToTypeID( "MnIt" );
        var idFtOn = charIDToTypeID( "FtOn" );
        ref3.putEnumerated( idMn, idMnIt, idFtOn );
    desc12.putReference( idnull, ref3 );
executeAction( idslct, desc12, DialogModes.NO );
```

Comment: Char ID's are those 4 character strings in that code you posted and you can convert them to string ID's, which might give you a better idea of what they do. These are in the javascript  reference PDF, but you got methods: `stringIDToTypeID(), charIDToTypeID(), typeIDToCharID(), typeIDToStringID()`, Unfortunately, you first need to convert to type id before you can convert to a string id: `alert( typeIDToStringID(charIDToTypeID('FtOn')) );`, which would return `fitOnScreen`. If I'm not totally wrong, that code is basically saying **Action:** `Select` **From:** `menu > menuitem > fit on screen`.

Comment: And you don't necessarily have to use character ID's in Action Manager code. [Here's basically the same code you posted with the string id `fitArtboardOnScreen`](https://pastebin.com/3mcQrSd9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can record it as an `Action` in PS 2020 and later. Though you have to use `Insert menu item...` from the Action panel's flyout menu (corner menu).

> I don't know the details, like if there's been bug reports or anything public, but I tested Photoshop `CC 2019, CC 2020, CC 2021, and CC 2022` and CC 2019 was the only version where that didn't work, so I'm making an assumption that all versions before CC 2020 have this issue and my best guess is that it was fixed when `View > Fit layer(s) on screen` was added around CC 2020.

In a script <sup><sub>(PS CC 2020+)</sub></sup> you could use a code similar to yours, but you can also use a simpler method:

```
app.runMenuItem( stringIDToTypeID('fitArtboardOnScreen') );
```

---

---

**If this is a productivity thing**, and doesn't have anything to do with automation, you can also `Alt + left click` the artboard name in the Layers panel.

Layers Panel <sup><sub>(PS CC 2020+)</sub></sup>:

1. **`Alt + left click` **on** the `artboard layer` (artboard name) → will fit the artboard on the screen**
2. `Alt + left click` **on** an `empty layer` or `Layer 0` → will fit all artboards on the screen
3. `Alt + left click` **on** `any other layer` → will fit that layer on the screen

   - The action itself works on multiple layers, but using this shortcut as the trigger you can only do one layer

---

---

You gave me a code example with `Fit on screen`, so I just wanted to let you know that it could also be shortened to the same `runMenuItem` command:

```
app.runMenuItem( stringIDToTypeID('fitOnScreen') );
```

Same goes for `Fit layers on screen` <sup><sub>(PS CC 2020+)</sub></sup>

```
app.runMenuItem( stringIDToTypeID('fitLayersOnScreen') );
```

Comment: Thank you.
I am NOT interested in "fit layer on screen".
I need "fit artboard on screen".

Comment: @Jenna, it's been kinda close to 2 years, but looking at my answer I don't understand where this comment is coming from? I did talk about other stuff, but I definitely prioritized fitting artboard to the screen and I don't think it's missing any information regarding it. If adding it as an action with `insert menu item` or the `runMenuItem()` method do not work, I would assume you have a version of PS where the bug is still a thing. Is you PS older than CC 2020? Even if it isn't, it's not unheard of for random things to break, especially when it comes to Actions or the JS API.